# Can a computers monitor be damaged by high lumens?

Tags: display, hardware-failure, webcam, physical-damage

Can high lumens damage a monitor? Some lasers can cause damage to camera lens.

Can a 120 lumen flashlight shining directly at a webcam or monitor cause damage to either one?

Comment: A flashlight or other non-coherent light source is unlikely to cause damage other than by heating (e.g. an infrared lamp could melt the plastic or destroy the liquid crystals). As for the camera, it would take a laser or direct sunlight to damage the sensor, again. other than from heat. The lens itself is just a hunk of glass or plastic.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik Do you think a 150 lumen flashlight, 1 inch away damage the webcam or monitor? Will it make enough heat to damage it? Will the magnifying glass effect make a difference?

Comment: If you really want to destroy it, try a blowtorch.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What are you actually trying to achieve? Remember that "You should only ask practical, answerable questions **based on actual problems that you face**."

Comment: I'm flagging this question as off-topic as it isn't directly related to hardware or computer monitors. This question is essentially asking about the physical properties of different materials and how they react to light, and pretty much applies to all electronics that have a screen.